Correct way of backing up emails from server (preferably with Thunderbird)
I have 3 work email accounts that will soon close. I currently access those accounts only with Thunderbird. I want to create a copy of all emails from the server into my local PC, this includes received and sent emails, together with attached files. I used the Tools → Export function which basically created a zip file with some of the contents of the ~/.thunderbird/22ff0zgu.default-release/ directory. The file is heavy, so I guess it contains all the emails from the server. But how can I be sure about this? Do I have to first force some kind of synchronization from Thunderbird and then do this?

I have used Import Export Tools NG. The only way I can think of to check the completeness is to import everything somewhere else and compare the two.

A couple of options. (You reference ~ so I assume it's a UNIX/Linux platform.)

Use a tool such as OfflineIMAP that will perform a real IMAP copy for you.

I believe this will also work under Windows but I've not tested it.
Make sure you read the associated documentation (start with man offlineimap), particularly if you need it to use OAUTH2 to authenticate to your email server.


Copy the mailbox directory tree to Thunderbird's Local Mail directory

In Thunderbird, create a mail folder under Local Mail that represents the root of the IMAP directory tree you want to copy. For example "Copy from Contoso".

Exit Thunderbird completely.

Copy the files from ImapMail/{imap-server-to-save} to Mail/Local Folders/Copy from Contoso.sbd, replacing imap-server-to-save with the appropriate directory representing your IMAP service you want to save:
cp -a ImapMail/{imap-server-to-save} 'Mail/Local Folders/Copy from Contoso.sbd'


Restart Thunderbird and check the folders have appeared.


Unfortunately I cannot guarantee that Thunderbird has downloaded all your messages. It's probable, but not guaranteed. If it's a significant issue use option #1 instead.


